Subgroup of a finitely generated abelian group

Let $G=\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/100\mathbb{Z}$. Let $H$ be the subgroup generated by the elements $(1,1,1)$ and $(1,2,3)$.

(1) What is the isomorphism class of $H$? $\\$
(2) What is the isomorphism class of $G/H$? $\\$
I've actually seen problems like this in my previous ring/module theory course, however $G$ would just be some $\mathbb{Z}^r$. I've tried to adapt the argument for part (1) as follows, but I'm a bit dubious of the result because I'm pretty sure I should be using structure theorem. Moreover, even if this first part is correct, I'm not sure how to do part (2) because I'm not sure what $G/\mathbb{Z}$ should look like.
First, define $\phi:\mathbb{Z}^2\to G$ by $\phi(a,b)=a(1,1,1)+b(1,2,3).$ We want to show this is a homomorphism. We have $$\phi((a,b)+(c,d))=\phi(a+c,b+d)=(a+c)(1,1,1)+(b+d)(1,2,3)=a(1,1,1)+c(1,1,1)+b(1,2,3)+d(1,2,3)$$ $$=\phi(a,b)+\phi(c,d)$$ Then since $(1,1,1)$ and $(1,2,3)$ generate $H$ we see that $im\phi=H.$ So by 1st Isomorphism Theorem, $$\mathbb{Z}^2/\ker\phi\cong H$$ We now aim to find $\ker\phi.$ We see that $(a,b)\in\ker\phi\iff$ $a(1,1,1)+b(1,2,3)=0\iff a+b=0$ and $a+2b=10p$ and $a+3b=100q$ for some $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}.$
Our first equation requires that $b=-a$ and our third thus says $-2a=100q\implies a=-50q.$ So $a$ has to be a multiple of 50 and $b$ has to be $-a.$ Thus $(a,b)\in\ker\phi\iff\exists k$ s.t $(a,b)=k(50,-50)\iff (a,b)\in \langle{(50,-50)}\rangle.$
Let $N$ be the subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ generated by $(50,-50).$ We claim $N\cong\mathbb{Z}.$ Indeed, letting $f:\mathbb{Z}\to N$ by $f(k)=(50k,-50k)$ we see that $f$ is clearly surjective and $(50a,-50a)=(50b,-50b)\iff a=b$ so $f$ is injective. Finally, $$f(a+b)=(50(a+b),-50(a+b))=(50a,-50a)+(50b,-50b)=f(a)+f(b)$$ So we conclude $$H\cong \mathbb{Z}^2/\ker\phi\cong\mathbb{Z}^2/\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Z}$$

(1) $H$ cannot be isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$, since it has torsion:$(1,2,3)-(1,1,1)=(0,1,2)$ and $50(0,1,2)=0$. Your mistake is in the very last step: $\Bbb Z^2/\Bbb Z$ is ambiguous; $\Bbb Z^2/(\Bbb Z\times\{0\})\cong\Bbb Z^2/(\{0\}\times\Bbb Z)\cong\Bbb Z$, but $$H\cong\Bbb Z^2/(50\Bbb Z(1,-1))=(\Bbb Z(1,0)\oplus\Bbb Z(1,-1))/(50\Bbb Z(1,-1))\cong\Bbb Z\times(\Bbb Z/50\Bbb Z).$$
(2) $G/H\cong\Bbb Z^3/K$ where (denoting by $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ the canonical basis of $\Bbb Z^3$)
$K=\langle k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4\rangle$ with $$k_1=10e_2,\;k_2=100e_3,\;k_3=e_1+e_2+e_3,\;k_4=e_1+2e_2+3e_3.$$
$K$ is also generated by
$$u:=k_3,\;v:=k_4-u,\;w:=k_1-10v=-20e_3,\;k_2+5w=0,$$
and $(u,v,e_3)=(e_1+e_2+e_3,e_2+2e_3,e_3)$ is another basis of $\Bbb Z^3$. Therefore,
$$G/H\cong(\Bbb Zu\oplus\Bbb Zv\oplus\Bbb Ze_3)/(\Bbb Zu\oplus\Bbb Zv\oplus\Bbb Z(20e_3))\cong\Bbb Z/20\Bbb Z.$$

This makes sense, thank you. For part (2), would I try to make sense of directly taking $G/H$? Or would I need to start over again with an entirely new argument. Intuitively I don't know what $G/H$ would even look like
